It is not fun anymore to contribute and read most questions
Why has this question (https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/9796/how-to-make-money, or this https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/9790/fastest-backtesting-engine [OP has been repeatedly asked to be more specific])  not been closed but put on hold or even left open?
I am really disappointed with the drop in quality and the hesitance of moderators to do much about it. I provided numerous suggestions and ideas how to screen first-time users (such as pre-screening of questions of those with less than x reps, more aggressive deletion of odd questions, answering some Qs before joining,...) , nothing has changed since the first day I joined. 
While I understand that nowadays every high school dropout calls himself a quant as soon as he has come across the term tick data or back-test/pricing engines I was hoping that a certain level of quality and professionalism will be upheld on this site but this is definitely not the case, especially not in the past couple months. 
I am just trying to be honest but I do not feel its fun anymore to contribute because its a pain to having to sift through all this garbage. 
Can't completely inappropriate questions be entirely deleted off the page and the user's account removed or the user warned that this was the first and only warning? I mean, there is a clear Q&A and signing up users should be aware of the requested (required?) format and which questions are definitely off-topic. Violate etiquette with your broker once and your line gets cut but here it seems repeat offenders are more than welcome. I remember when I joined and had a bit of an argument that my entire account was put on hold. Seems I was mistaken and that this must have happened on a different website. 
Can't something be done to uphold the professionalism of this website? I am willing to get engaged and help out. But should nothing be done I do not think I will stick around for too much longer. It gets embarrassing to have clients and colleagues see my profile right next to questions about NinjaTrader and content where users have no idea about the difference between tick and compressed 'bar' or what have you type of time series data. If such questions are welcome here then could someone please make it clear to me so that I can make up my own mind to continue to spend my time here or elsewhere. 

FWIW, I started full-time work in the industry in Sep-2013, and I'm trying to be more active in the community. I'd like to see more close-votes from community members, rather than rely on mods... but a mod re-opening the "fastest backtesting engine" has me scratching my head.

I vote to close quite liberally these days. It seems to be the same small group of non-mods doing the voting. I've no idea why this particular back testing question was re-opened. I doubt the question itself would even survive on Stack Overflow as a general programming question since it's so poorly framed. Can the mod that re-opened this thing please chime in as to why? Also, I can't seem to RE-vote to close the  damn thing, which is lame. In fact, my first comment that the question was "ignorant" (which it is) was mysteriously deleted by some mod as well, why?

I'll also add that @chrisaycock was the most pro-active mod at closing things and enforcing the professional underpinnings of the site. From glancing at his profile, he hasn't been around in about a month.

Joshua & Louis, thanks for your take on this. I second what you, Louis, said about @chrisaycock who was very proactive and involved in keeping things in order and I appreciated it a lot. I have not noticed his absence because I have not been around much myself but his absence could be a reason for so many off-topic and too-broad questions sneaking in. In any case its bad for this site and the community should really consider what to do about it, which is why I brought up this topic.

I can only agree on this. The quality has been dropping over the last 6 months. I also think this is due to a lack of (good) questions. Also, many answers are one-liners, often not even tackling the question at hand and with a dubious line of argument. Maybe it helps if people use the downvote function on answers more often... because no one wants to ask questions here if he's likely to get answers of that kind.

Fully agree; the quality of recent material is low.  Partly since most of the truly high-quality questions with relatively simple answers have been addressed already.  18+ months we got questions and answers like http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/3302/deriving-spot-rates-from-treasury-yield-curve.  Now, "good" questions are far more complex to answer, like http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/9746/expected-shortfall-cvar-backtesting.  It's an interesting question but quite possibly no one knows the answer.  Thus, the answerable questions skew toward being bad questions these days.

I feel like I've been logging in pretty regularly (except on vacation, which is why some of those questions were slow to be closed), but I haven't seen as many questions I really wanted to answer in recent months. Either stuff is too complex for me to confidently answer or it's too obvious to be interesting (sorry @BrianB but I felt that way about the question you thought was good).

Please keep voting on the better questions and answers. IMO there is some decent material on the frontpage with little votes. Show others what you like.

@John That was my impression too - some (if not most, as is in my case) of the interesting questions are quite specific and I feel uneasy answering them (would happily read some answers though) and a lot of more general/approachable questions are not interesting enough for me to go for a comprehensive answer (I don't like one-liners either).  Maybe I have to brush up a bit on my rusty skills to participate in a larger number of fields or maybe the site is not yet big enough to generate enough content for every niche (you could spend your life just monitoring/answering a single tag on SO).

I am not a hardcore user of any of the sub-stackexchanges, so I don't know what the usual etiquette is, but certainly is nice to have one devoted to quant finance.  That said, I had always assumed that its domain was really just a goose step away from applied mathematics, which is exactly where I like it.  If there is a persistent demand by other folks for a place to ask questions and have discussions about financial data/technology/technical analysis/witchcraft, perhaps there's another sub-stackexchange they can be moved to, or one created?  

I'm not sure that would help. Many people think, "running a regression on financial data makes me a quant" or, "building an automated trading strategy makes me a quant". It reminds me of something a colleague once told me, "Some people think a table summary statistics is quantitative analysis." We probably need to be more specific in the FAQ regarding what is/isn't on-topic.

Yeah, I jumped off the site a while back. I got tired of fighting with non-quants every day. The only reason I logged on today was some web searching brought me here and I noticed a few old questions that needed canonical answers. I doubt I'll be around much in the future. I tried to get StackExchange, Inc to remove me as a moderator long ago, but my request was bizarrely denied.

I can understand why you got tired. Might I suggest that you hang around, but simply ignore the off-topic, non-quant questions? What's left of the community can't really afford to lose more contributors like you.

I assume the down-vote is disapproval of you leaving the site. ;)

When you say "fighting with non-quants", what do you mean by "fighting"?
